# What can make a file become binary after being wirtten on?

Tags: java, encryption, binaryfiles

In case the question wasn't that clear, I was wondering in the process of writing data into a file, what types of input or operations can make them turn from text files to binary files?

Reason for the question:
I was just starting my way into (Java) cryptography and I made a simple program that reads the text from an existing file and, after encrypting it, it writes the encrypted message back in that file.

Problem:
Sometimes the file stays "text", showing some ramdom symbols and letters from the encryption, but other times it turns into a binary file and despite running some tests, I can't seem to understand what could be the cause.

Example:

-with document containing the word "test",
expected output:`�Ҋ5�)>;`

result in File: `�Ҋ5�)>;`

-with document containing the word "Message",
expected output:`�̮�~��<-�L��%`

result in File: File turned into binary

Note: I'm pretty much positive it does not depend on the word, and I had a guess it could be related to what encryption symbols it generates, but I could be wrong.

In case it's useful:
I'm currently using Ubunto and creating the text file with "gedit".

Code: (I appologize for the try/catches)

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException{

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  
    System.out.println("Nome fo ficheiro:");
    String fileName = sc.nextLine();
    byte [] byteMsg = getByteMsg(fileName);


    //* Declare Encriptor--> Cipher//
    Cipher cifrador = null;
    try {
         cifrador = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
        System.out.println("Problema na mensagem");
    }


    //* Generate key -->  KeyGenerator*//
    KeyGenerator kgen = null;
    try{
        kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
    }
    catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        System.out.println("Algoritmo de encriptação não encontrado");
    }
    SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();


    //* Inicialize Encritptor and encrypt message* --> Cipher//
    try {
        cifrador.init(1, key);   //1 = Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE

    } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
        System.out.println("Chave de cifragem inválida");
    }
    byte[]byteMsgCod = null;
    try {
        byteMsgCod = cifrador.doFinal(byteMsg);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
        System.out.println("Tamanho de Bloco Ilegal");
    } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
        System.out.println("Bad Padding");
    }  



    //* Write encrypted message in the file*//
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fileName);
    String msgCod = new String(byteMsgCod);
    System.out.println(msgCod);
    pw.println(msgCod);
    pw.close();



    /* Read text from file */   
}
private static byte[] getByteMsg(String fileName) throws IOException{
    //Ler msg do ficheiro
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Ficheiro não encontrado");
    }

    byte[] byteMsg = new byte[fis.available()];

    fis.close();

    return byteMsg;
}
```

Comment: **All** files are binary

Comment: All files are binary. What you're seeing are non-printable characters (characters less than 32 decimal (0x20). See any ASCII chart.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm not sure  if I got this correctly, but would that mean that when non-printable characters are generated by the encryption, the file format changes to suit the fact that not all of them are printable and thefore displayeable in a normal "text" format?

Comment: The format doesn't change at all. Once again, **all files are binary**. There is no format change whatsoever. What changes is how they appear when you display them, because **some characters are non-printable**. Again, see any [ASCII chart](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**All files are binary files**.  There isn't really such a thing as a "text file" in the sense that you seem to understand it.

There is  such a thing as a file that, by chance, happens to contain a sequence of encoded bytes that perfectly represent a UTF8 string of characters.  But it's still a binary file.

The same can be said for any other encoding ever.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all files being binary:

1. Encrypted data is not text.
2. `String` is not a container for binary data.
3. `Writers` are not a valid way to write binary data.
4. There is a specific warning in the Javadoc against using `available()` the way you're using it.

Comment: `PrintWriter` was used, same difference.